# Error Using JointJS when canvas is inner DIV

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I had actually noticed this issue over a year ago but wasn't ready to really dig into the library to use it at the time.  Now the time has come when I really need to use JointJS (or something like it) and the issue still exists.

If I have markup like the following:

```
<div>
  <div id="world"></div>
</div>
```

I get the following error in Firebug for any kind of JointJS diagram.

```
a[0] is undefined.
```

Making the "world" div stand on its own with no parent works just fine.  Anyone else have this problem and figured out a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried `Joint.paper(document.getElementById("world"))` ?
Works for me ...